# Flutter validation called on null in Login page

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to do my first app but I don't know how to use validator.

I tried to move all in myLogin class and i tried to split my code to find the problem.

I set formkey as global varible (with mail and pass variables).

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

String _email, _password;
final formKey = new GlobalKey < FormState > ();

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
...
}

class myLogin extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _myLogin createState() => _myLogin();
}

class _myLogin extends State < myLogin > {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Title",
      home: Scaffold(
        body: (
          Column(
            children: [
              titleRow,
            ],
          )
        )
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

This is my screen.

```
Widget titleRow = Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 40, 40, 40),

    child: Form(
      key: formKey,

      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(

            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [

                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Email: "),
                  validator: (value) => !value.contains('@') ? "Not a valid Email" : null,
                  onSaved: (value) => _email = value
                ),

                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Password: "),
                  validator: (value) => value.length < 8 ? "At least 8 character" : null,
                  onSaved: (value) => _password = value,
                  obscureText: true
                ),

                OutlineButton(
                  child: new Text("Sign In"),
                  onPressed: funLogin(),
                  shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))
                )
              ]

            )
          )
          ]
        ) 
    )
);


funLogin() {
  final form = formKey.currentState;
  if (form.validate()) {
    form.save();
    print(_email);
    print(_password);
  }
}
```

The Android emulator return error:

"NoSuchMethodError: The method validate was called on null"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the function inside an onpressed so you should use it like this

```
onPressed : ()=> your function
```

Comment: Thank you!! I tried only to correct the validation point. It solves my problem